# When using django rest frame work modlerserializers passwords don't get hashed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

if I use a ModelSerializer class from django-rest-framework how might I make sure passwords are hashed? as calling modelSerializer.save() does not hash fields called 'password'? is there a way to specify that a field needs to be hashed in  "Meta:" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do such kind of transformation, you can do two things:

- use `validate_xxx` to change the field-value when validating (see the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#validation))
- create a [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#custom-fields) definition if you use this kind of behavior more times.

If you are talking about a Django user model, you could define a `pre_save` method on the serializer that calls `User.set_password`.

Comment: I think this is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the unserialized request object and hashing the password before I serialized it django makes this easy with the make_password

```
    def prehash(self, request):            
        password = request.DATA['password']
        password = make_password(password)
        request = request.DATA
        request = request.copy()
        request.update({'password':password})
        return request
```